# How to import other type definitions in my custom type definition files

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a TypeScript library for React and need to create custom type definitions ( `index.d.ts` ).

In generally, developers do not need to import type definitions for some libraries explicitly and all they need to do is installing `@types/` packages in latest TypeScript.

My library is depending on React and its type definitions ( `@types/react` ) and I want to import React type definitions in custom type definitions ( `index.d.ts` ) like the following.

```
// index.d.ts
/// <reference types="node" />
import { HtmlHTMLAttributes } from "@types/react";

declare module "*.bar" {
  const value: HtmlHTMLAttributes;
  export default value;
}
```

But the definitions do not work fine and throw error "Cannot find module".

I have two questions,

1. Which is correct, to install `@types/react` as "dependencies", or to do as "devDependencies"?
2. How to import other type definitions in my custom type definitions and use them?

---

**EDITED**

I use import syntax `from "react"` instead of `from "@types/react"`, then when I write the following code, it throws error `Cannot find  module 'foo.bar'.` .

```
// sample.ts
import * as Foo from "foo.bar";
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

But removing import syntax from the definition, it does not throw errors.

```
// index.d.ts
/// <reference types="node" />
// import { HtmlHTMLAttributes } from "react"; <-- Remove
declare module "*.bar" {
...

// sample.ts
import * as Foo from "foo.bar"; // <-- does not throw errors.
```

This library is depending on type definitions of React, but does not need to include React, so I do not install `react` .

```
// package.json
...
dependencies: {},
devDependencies: {
  "@types/react": "^16.4.9"
},
...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which line is the error on?  You should `import { HtmlHTMLAttributes } from "react"`, not `"@types/react"`; even if your definition file compiles OK with `"@types/react"`, other people may be unable to use it.

Comment: As @MattMcCutchen said, you should try to import the definition from the library itself and not from the types. Also, to answer your first question, `@types` should be in `devDependencies` simply because the code in production should be transpiled into es2015 which doesn't understand type definitions.

Comment: Thank you. Fix to import from `react` instead of `@types/react`, but it does not work fine. I just edited the question, please read it.